# mod_rewrite to serve html pages through php script

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

First of all, I've set my rewrite rule to allow the removal of .html from the URL.

I've also created a php script that I want to serve all of my HTML pages. This way, I can create and link to a simple html page, but it will be handled by my php script.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/webpage.php?view=webpage_handler&file=$1.html [L]
```

So instead of linking to www.mysite.com/page.html I link to www.mysite.com/page which allows me to access the page.html through webpage.php

I would also like to be able link to the page.html in some other cases (without removing the .html extension) and still have my webpage.php handle the page view.

I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/webpage.php?view=webpage_handler&file=$1.html [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*\.(html))$ /folder/webpage.php?view=webpage_handler&file=$1 [L]
```

but this does not work like expected. I'm not sure if the second rule is working at all, and I do believe they're conflicting each other... but I don't know how to fix it.

Is there a safe way to allow me to link to both "/page.html" and "/page" and get my expected outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more trial and error, I've learned that what I had was actually correct. For some reason my "view" variable was getting erased which was causing my script to not function properly.

My $_GET['view'] variable was blank in webpage.php but the $_GET['file'] variable was set like it should.

I changed from

```
view=webpage_handler
```

to

```
view=handle_webpage
```

That's it. It works fine now. Obviously it was something I did, but I have no clue what.